# how to solve "Illegal byte sequence" issue when converting a nc file into csv one?

Tags: python, netcdf

I'm trying to convert a netcdf file into a csv one

```py
import xarray as xr
import os

netcdf_file_name = r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\논문14. War, Grid\raw nc data\precip.mon.ltm.nc'

netcdf_file_in = netcdf_dir + netcdf_file_name
csv_file_out = csv_dir + netcdf_file_name[:-3] + '.csv'

ds = xr.open_dataset(netcdf_file_in)
df = ds.to_dataframe()

df.to_csv(csv_file_out)
```

I get

> [Errno 42] Illegal byte sequence:
> b'C:\Users\User\Desktop\\xeb\x85\xbc\xeb\xac\xb814. War,
> Grid\data
> testnetcdf\C:\Users\User\Desktop\\xeb\x85\xbc\xeb\xac\xb814. War,
> Grid\raw nc data\precip.mon.ltm.nc'

from the above code. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure what your exact issue is, but do you mean to have two complete file paths? It seems like netcdf_file_name is your full path, so you don't need netcdf_file_in.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the _complete_ error traceback.